# Accessing libnetlink.h

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to access some member variables within libnetlink.h, but when I #include  in my source and compile with "gcc source.c -o binary", I get a "fatal error: libnetlink.h: No such file or directory" error.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and I've already installed libnl-3-dev via apt-get install.

Comment: add `-I/usr/include/libnl3/netlink` ... and the header is called `netlink.h` as far as I can tell

Comment: What filename do you specify for `#include`? According to the [manual](http://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/doc/core.html) you need to add the path: `#include <netlink/netlink.h>`

Comment: I'm trying to follow some example code at https://blog.croz.net/en/blog/xfrm-programming/ to set up IPSec SA using XFRM. The example code has #include <libnetlink.h> but I can't figure out how to get it to compile as I don't have that library header nor do I know how to obtain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the correct path that must be seen from your source file.
this can be done by either:

1: **Full path** of the file 'libnetlink.h' like this (for example in linux):

**/home/username/Desktop/folder1/libnetlink.h**

2: **Relative path** of the file, corresponding to where your source file exist:
suppose your source file exist on 'Desktop', and your libnetlink.h exist in sub folder of Desktop folders called 'folder1', then the path will:

**folder1/libnetlink.h**

Comment: Thanks. I ended up downloading both libnetlink.h and libnetlink.c and just including them in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following command may help.

`apt-get iproute-dev`

I am using Fedora Core 26, after installing iproute-dev, the same problem is solved.